# Google Sheets: Change TabColor depends TabName or Cell Value

Tags: google-sheets, colors, tabs

I am trying to change tab color depends if TabName is on a RANG table or Cell Value.

Thanks u so much!

Trying to Change TabColor.

Answer (score 1):

This Code is awesome but need check all sheets and load J1 cell automatically:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() != "J1") return;

  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (e.value == '0' || !e.value)  sheet.setTabColor(undefined);
  if (e.value == '1') sheet.setTabColor('red');
  if (e.value == '2') sheet.setTabColor('blue');
}
```